# Vacation in Europe for seafarer

Tags: schengen, europe, us-citizens, visa-free-entry

I'm US citizen working on a cruise ship. I will disembark in Venice and would like to stay in there for vacation. Do I need to leave the Schengen area and re-enter as a tourist?

Comment: The easy way it is to ask other crew members, they know a lot better (and from experience). In larger harbor you can "enter as tourist" [yacht are not so seldom]. Check where you should go to have validated your entry

Comment: Is Venice the first port of call in the Schengen area? What visa(s) do you have, if any? How many days have you been in the Schengen area in the last 180 and on what basis?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.